# Doctrine don't transform my colons

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dbal

My colons are never transformed into the parameters value

```
    $queryBuilder
        ->select('p.id', 'p.quantite', 'p.dateAjoutPanier', 'p.prix, p.user_id', 'v.nom', 'p.produit_id')
        ->from('paniers', 'p')
        ->innerJoin('p', 'produits', 'v', 'p.produit_id=v.id')
        ->where('p.user_id = :userid')
        ->andWhere('p.produit_id = :produitid')
        ->setParameter('produitid',(int)1)
        ->setParameter('userid',(int)1);
    return $queryBuilder->getSQL();
```

this code return : 
SELECT p.id, p.quantite, p.dateAjoutPanier, p.prix, p.user_id, v.nom, p.produit_id FROM paniers p INNER JOIN produits v ON p.produit_id=v.id WHERE (p.user_id = :userid) AND (p.produit_id = :produitid)

Someone have the problem (or the solution) ?

Comment: Did you expect the sql to contain the values?  Does not work that way.  You still need to prepare the statement and pass it your parameters.  See DBAL::executeQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected more than one rows you should use the loop to iterate over each key - value entity.

But if you have only one row, use `getSingleResult()` or `getOneOrNullResult()` methods with `setMaxResults(1)`

For example:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('p.id', 'p.quantite', 'p.dateAjoutPanier', 'p.prix, p.user_id', 'v.nom', 'p.produit_id')
    ->from('paniers', 'p')
    ->innerJoin('p', 'produits', 'v', 'p.produit_id=v.id')
    ->where('p.user_id = :userid')
    ->andWhere('p.produit_id = :produitid')
    ->setParameter('produitid',1)
    ->setParameter('userid',1)
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult();
```